# Why does Kinesis Fire Hose restrict HTTP endpoints to port 443 (or no port at all)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

See screenshot below.  When I attempted to create an instance of Kinesis Fire Hose with delivery to an HTTP endpoint such as `https://my-custom-endpoint.acme.io:9443`, the create-request failed.  Why?

Clearly there are work-arounds for this issue.  But why impose a restriction like this?  I can't be the first person who would want to specify an endpoint with an uncommon port for receiving Fire Hose events.

[image]

Comment: Currently, Kinesis Data Firehose only support port 443 for HTTP endpoint data delivery.

Comment: @ArpitJain:  I hope AWS has not frozen support for 443 only.  I can imagine many circumstances why someone might want to get data chunks from Fire Hose on some port other than 443.

Comment: They have mentioned it in their docs :)